# Ckedior not setting LTR text direction in the source

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor4.x, ng-ckeditor

When a user click on the RTL button ckedior is adding a direction with RTL.

While when clicking on LTR it just removes the style it and not stetting it to LTR.

Is there a way to make it set it even on LTR?

Comment: I removed the ckeditor5 tag because your question seems to be CKEditor 4 related.

Comment: Why what is the difference in relation to LTR?

Comment: There's no BiDi plugin for CKEditor 5 yet. So when you write "when the user clicks on the RTL button", then you are most likely referring to CKEditor 4.